# Delete multiple columns using column numbers

Tags: excel, vba

Just wanted to share as I had huge amount of trouble looking for ways to do this online and have finally gotten it through series of trial and error.

Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, 11), Cells(1, 100)).EntireColumn.Delete

This deletes columns 11 to 100.

Comment: Columns/Rows A11 - A100 you mean

Comment: @ScottFiander - take another look...

Comment: Note - this will fail if Sheet1 isn't the active sheet. `Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 11), Sheet1.Cells(1, 100))`

Comment: Oh yes Tim sorry I edited my code on my end but not here.

Comment: And where do you type this in excel? @Jay

Answer (score 8):

```
With Sheet1
    .Range(.Cells(1, 11), .Cells(1, 100)).EntireColumn.Delete
End With
```

Answer (score 8):

More ways

**Deleting consecutive columns like 1 - 100**

```
Sub Sample()
    With Sheet1
        'A:CV
        .Columns(ReturnName(1) & ":" & ReturnName(100)).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End With
End Sub

'~~> Returns Column Name from Col No
Function ReturnName(ByVal num As Integer) As String
    ReturnName = Split(Cells(, num).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

**Deleting non consecutive columns like  1, 3, 5**

```
Sub Sample()
    With Sheet1
        'A:A,C:C,E:E
        .Range( _
                ReturnName(1) & ":" & ReturnName(1) & "," & _
                ReturnName(3) & ":" & ReturnName(3) & "," & _
                ReturnName(5) & ":" & ReturnName(5) _
               ).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End With
End Sub

Function ReturnName(ByVal num As Integer) As String
    ReturnName = Split(Cells(, num).Address, "$")(1)
End Function

'**Another way**

Sub Sample()
    Dim Rng As Range

    With Sheet1
        Set Rng = Union(.Columns(1), .Columns(3), .Columns(5))
    End With

    Rng.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Sid, although I might just use the one I have posted since it's one-liner and easier for me to understand. For doing this with multiple non-consecutive columns, Union() look's great and I will start using that as I have not heard of this until today :)