# Excel VBA: Delete multiple columns using variable containing column numbers

Tags: vba, excel

Because of the high chances of the arrangement of columns being adjusted in my raw data, I want to store the column numbers in variables.

I think that my syntax `Columns(Variable_name)` is wrong, but can't figure what will work

I tried `Columns("Variable_name")` which didn't work too.

```
Set Cws = Worksheets.Add
Cws.Name = "Ready_For_Send"

Dim Region As Integer: Region = 1
Dim Sub_Region As Integer: Sub_Region = 2
Dim User_Status As Integer: User_Status = 5
Dim Count As Integer: Count = 15

With Cws
  .Range(.Columns(Region) & "," & .Columns(Sub_Region) & "," & .Columns(User_Status) & "," & Columns(Count)).Delete
End With
```

Comment: What kind of error message are you getting? What line is the code failing at? Part of the code appears to be missing e.g. there needs to be a reference to the workbook you are adding the sheet too and also a declaration of the worksheet Cws as worksheet.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
With Cws
    .Range(Cells(1, Region).EntireColumn.Address & "," _
      & Cells(1, Sub_Region).EntireColumn.Address & "," _
      & Cells(1, User_Status).EntireColumn.Address & "," _
      & Cells(1, Count).EntireColumn.Address).Delete
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Union` to merge all your columns to one `Range`, and then delete it.

Try the code below:

```
Dim DelRng As Range

With Cws
    ' Set a new range from all the columns you want to delete
    Set DelRng = Union(.Columns(Region), .Columns(Sub_Region), .Columns(User_Status), .Columns(Count))
    DelRng.Delete
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteCols()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Csw As Worksheet
Dim Region As Long
Dim Sub_Region As Long
Dim User_Status As Long
Dim Count As Long
Dim Cws As Worksheet

Region = 1
Sub_Region = 2
User_Status = 5
Count = 15

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
Set Cws = wb.Worksheets.Add
Cws.Name = "Ready_For_Send"
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

With Cws

.Range( _
           ReturnName(Region) & ":" & ReturnName(Region) & "," & _
           ReturnName(Sub_Region) & ":" & ReturnName(Sub_Region) & "," & _
           ReturnName(User_Status) & ":" & ReturnName(User_Status) & "," & _
           ReturnName(Count) & ":" & ReturnName(Count) _
           ).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End With

End Sub

Function ReturnName(ByVal num As Integer) As String
   ReturnName = Split(Cells(, num).Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

Some structure and Function from here: [Delete multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878062/delete-multiple-columns-using-column-numbers)

I have included error handling in case sheet already exists. Also full declarations. I have also put declarations and assignments on different lines for ease of reading.